# Serial Terminal with custom colors

Tags: serial-port, serial

Looked around but I can't seem to find a serial terminal program that has ability to custom color lines according to certain symbols found in received lines. For example I would like to see 'ERROR: explanation' highlighted in red until the next line break is received. Has anyone came by across something like it?

Edit:
Machines that are connected to serial interface run Windows and running a VM on them is not an options.

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal emulator supports ANSI, it supports colors:

- http://tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/65/padala.html
- http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.7

While those are linux examples, they are applicable to any ANSI terminal emulator.  ANSI escape sequences are interpreted by the emulator, and the display is written accordingly.

Comment: Problem is, the host system has to add those to its output. I suspect Nickolay may be looking for something that performs lexical coloring based on scanning the received data.

Comment: Ohhh, I did not consider that.  If that is so, it might be possible to create a little device in the middle to automatically handle that.  But otherwise, I think a custom terminal emulator may be required in order to make that happen.

Comment: Or any of the open source terminal emulators available could be extended with the translation functionality as the OP wishes. That's one of the many positive aspects of open-source software.

Comment: Yea I was planning on extending an open source project if there wasn't an out of box answer just didn't want to re-invent the wheel if some project already has that functionality

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a terminal emulator that can do this, but, oddly enough, Zsh is configurable enough to do it. Check out [this blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/qmvfya) about adding syntax highlighting to Zsh. You might be able to implement what you want from that.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) support serial interfaces and it supports standard [VT-style escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) for setting color/bold/flashing. PuTTY is pretty much defacto standard in UNIX/Linux industry.

Answer (score 0):

Termite (https://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm) has a "Highlight" plug in that you can set to highlight specific text, case sensitive or not. The source code for it is posted so you can improve it at will. https://www.compuphase.com/software/termite_filter_highlight.zip
v/r,
Rob (no relation or connection to Termite other than a user)